# A question on the proof of induced metric from Riemannian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

The following Picture is the proof of "*distance function on Riemannian manifold is a metric*".

[image: Page-4]

How the author deduced that length of any curve from $p$ to the boundary of given ball is at least $r/\lambda_0$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write down the integral for the length of any path from $p$ to the boundary of the ball (presumably they're choosing $r$ so that the point $q$ lies outside the ball). If you have a symmetric matrix $A(x)$ whose smallest positive eigenvalue is at least $\lambda_0$, what can you say about $\sqrt{u^\top A(x) u}$ for any vector $u$? Now integrate the appropriate expression to get the length of the path, and what's the lower bound you have?

Comment: Is $\lambda_0\leq \sqrt{u^\top A(x) u}$ correct ?

Comment: $\lambda_0\|u\|$?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. is $\sqrt{u^\top g_x u}=\sqrt{g_x(u,u)}$?

Comment: Remember that the Riemannian metric is given by a positive definite symmetric matrix.